# Can you create a MySQL DB via cPanel API json call?

Tags: php, perl, api, cakephp-1.3, cpanel

I am looking to automate the creation of a MySQL database via a json api call. To list dbs, I can just use something like:

```
https://example.com:2083/json-api/cpanel?user=username&cpanel_jsonapi_module=MysqlFE&cpanel_jsonapi_func=listdbs&cpanel_jsonapi_version=2
```

This is successful via HTTP Sockets and CURL. Is there any equivalent call for adddb?

```
https://example.com:2083/json-api/cpanel?user=username&cpanel_jsonapi_module=Mysql&cpanel_jsonapi_func=adddb&dbname=aa1&cpanel_jsonapi_version=1
```

This doesn't work. I get the following error:

â€œusername_â€ is an invalid database name. It contains invalid characters.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I am running this via an HTTP Socket connection in CakePHP with the following code:

```
$query = 'cpanel_jsonapi_module=MysqlFE&cpanel_jsonapi_func=adddb&dbname=aa1&cpanel_jsonapi_version=2';

$request = array(
            'auth' => array(
                'user' => $queryData['conditions']['username'],
                'pass' => $queryData['conditions']['password'],
                'method' => 'Basic',
            ),
            'uri' => array(
                'scheme' => 'https',
                'host' => $queryData['conditions']['host'],
                'port' => '2083',
                'user' => $queryData['conditions']['username'],
                'path' => 'json-api/cpanel',
                'query' => $query,
            ),
        );
    $result = json_decode($this->connection->request($request), true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. In order to create / delete a DB through the cPanel API, it must be processed through API 1. The API access is a little bit different.

You must first get the theme your cPanel account is using (StatsBar:stat (theme):

```
https://example.com:2083/json-api/cpanel?user=USERNAME&cpanel_jsonapi_module=StatsBar&cpanel_jsonapi_func=stat&display=theme&cpanel_jsonapi_version=2
```

Then you plug that theme into another request:

```
https://example.com:2083/frontend/THEME/sql/addb.html?db=aa1
```

Of course, you must have the Authentication in the HTTP Socket (or CURL). Works like a charm!

Comment: API 1 is obsolete. please use API2

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/ApiDocs/Api1/ApiMysql#Mysql::adddb

You've got dbname in the url twice but I don't know if that matters...

I'm not sure how the url API works, you could try ..._jsonapi_func=adddb(thedbname) but I have no clue if that would work.

Comment: I edited the post to reflect a single dbname request. Thanks for pointing that out. The actual code does not have multiple dbname fields. I have read the API docs prior to this post. But I tried your suggestion and got `syntax error at (eval 6) line 1, near ")("`. But thanks for the feedback.